# @Inject Annotation of 2 constructors for 2 dependent classes in Java

Tags: java, constructor, dependencies, inject

Here is the code I am trying :

public class ClassA {

```
   private final String check;
   private final ClassB classB;

   //ClassA constructor

   @Inject

   public ClassA(String check, ClassB classB) {

     this.check = check + "A";
     this.classB = classB;

   }

   public String getCheck() {

         String check = classB.getCheck();
         print(check) ///////////////return checkA
   }

 }
```

public class ClassB {

```
  private final String check;

 //ClassB constructor

 @Inject

 public ClassB(String check) {

    this.check = check + "B";

 }

 public String getCheck() { 

      return check;
    }
  }
```

So, when @Inject is annotated for both the constructors, classB.getCheck(); should return checkB but it returns checkA. I assume this is because the classB constructor is not being executed due to @Inject annotations. But I am not sure of the exact reason. Any suggestion what I am missing?

Comment: What value is expected to be **injected** for `private final String check;`

Comment: . Just wanna know why checkA is returned even after calling CheckB class getCheck method

Comment: Have you even tried running your code? How did you get away with this `public class getCheck()`. Please provide a minimal verifiable code.